# Combine label, textview and image (but image is scroll with text)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder

I want to create an view that include;

- UITextView
- UILabel
- UIImageView

Half of the view is imageview `(x:0 y:0 w:320 h:230)`
other size completely text with scrolling or not. But I don't want to image is fixed position image must scroll with text.

Finally I want to add label on imageview(label is fixed bottom of the imageview,and background transparant)

Should I use `ScrollView`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the step 
 view -> scrollview -> tableview 
  Inside tableview Header part used for UItextview and UIimageview for footer and if u place a label in imageview.

Comment: Hi CNSivakumar, but text size is not static it came from web services. So it can be 2 line or 30 line? If the tableView first row for image, second row for text: how can ı organize row height according to text size?

As you say if I put textView it scroll itself.But I want to scroll image and text together and text size unpredictable.

Comment: Hi NevzatR, if u calculated the dynamic string length or font size and length or font value is used to adjust the height of text view.                   
  
Example: textView.frame(x,y,width,length);
  
   if more space means using condition to adjust size .

(or)

CGSize lengthwise = [length.text sizeWithFont:length.font];
 using lengthsize.width to adjust the size of textview.

Comment: I solve it thank you :)) but you can edit your answer I am not use a table view it is not necessary, UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIImageView + UITextView... Organizing textview height according to text size, also scrollview height, disable scrolling for textview and thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view is what your looking for. Put the imageview inside it along with the text view below it then they will both scroll together

Comment: Hi Disco, you are right firstly I try it but text size is unpredictable so textview scroll insidely itself also... But I don't want to.. text and image is fixed both of it shoul scroll together.

Answer (score 0):

For the UIImageView, you could put it inside a UIView with clipping turned on.  As the UITextView scrolls, change the UIImageView's frame's origin vertically which will give the scroll effect.  I implemented a filmstrip knob in this manner and it worked out great.  The label can go in the view containing the UIImageView.  It will remain fixed since you would only be changing the ImageView's origin.

Comment: Hi Sam, do you have any idea how can I change UIImageView.origin.y same time with textview scrolling?And it must also change textview origin am i right? Because at the beginning UITextView origin is (x:0 y:230 w:320 h:230) y should be y-- when we do scroll...

Comment: UITextView inherits from UIScrollView, so if you use the delegate of the UIScrollView (might have to do [super setDelegate:] to set it), you can take advantage of the scrollViewDidScroll event.
 Looks like you found a solution that works though!  So that's good.
Sorry for not responding sooner.  I only just barely realized you added a comment.  Still getting used to StackOverflow.  Maybe theres a way to setup an e-mail notification for that.